# Reducir array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, reduce

Tenemos es siguiente array:

```
    const array = [
    {id: 1, amount: 20}, 
    {id: 3, amount: 50}, 
    {id: 2, amount: 80}, 
    {id: 1, amount: 70}, 
    {id: 3, amount: 60},
    {id: 1, amount: 20}
    ]
```

Necesitamos retornar un array de objetos que no repita el id y que sume lo que tenemos en el campo amount de cada objeto. La salida esperada para este array sería:

```
const res = [
{id: 1, amount: 110},
{id: 2, amount: 80},
{id: 3, amount: 110}
]
```

Cuál sería la solución más óptima.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? No hacemos los deberes de los demás. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Preguntar por la forma más óptima es hacer que tu pregunta tienda a ser basada en opiniones. Además, como te han indicado, debes adjuntar un [repro] en la pregunta (por más que sea una pregunta autorrespondida). [es.so] _no es un repositorio de código_. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma pude obtener la solución:

```js
const array = [
    {id: 1, amount: 20}, 
    {id: 3, amount: 50}, 
    {id: 2, amount: 80}, 
    {id: 1, amount: 70}, 
    {id: 3, amount: 60},
    {id: 1, amount: 20}
    ]

const returnItemsSumOnArray = (array) => {
      const mapSum = new Map();

      // agrega los valores al hash table
      array.forEach((element) => {
        const storedValue = mapSum.get(element.id);
        mapSum.set(
          element.id,
          storedValue ? storedValue + element.amount : element.amount
        );
      });

      // convierte hash table en un array
      const arraySum = [];
      for (var [id, amount] of mapSum.entries()) {
        arraySum.push({ id, amount });
      }
      return arraySum;
    };

console.log(returnItemsSumOnArray(array));
```

Espero sea de utilidad para quienes tengan una inquietud similar.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Establecemos la

```
condicion if (!total[currentValue.id])
```

para
construir un objeto  de tipo Por ejemplo :

```
"total[key]",  {
  "id": 2,
  "amount": 0
}
```

luego  poblamos result
Fuera de la condición acumulamos el valor de amount para cada id

```
interface monto{
  id:number;
  amount:number
}
const array :monto[] = [
  {id: 1, amount: 20}, 
  {id: 3, amount: 50}, 
  {id: 2, amount: 80}, 
  {id: 1, amount: 70}, 
  {id: 1, amount: 20}, 
  {id: 3, amount: 60}, 

  ]
let result:monto[] = [];
array.reduce(function(total:any ,
currentValue) {
 if (!total[currentValue.id]) {
     console.log('currentValue:',currentValue);
     let key=currentValue.id
    total[key] = { id:key, amount: 0 };
  
    result.push(total[currentValue.id])
  }
  total[currentValue.id].amount += currentValue.amount;
  return total;
}, {});

console.log('result',result)
```

en js

```js
const array= [
  {id: 1, amount: 20}, 
  {id: 3, amount: 50}, 
  {id: 2, amount: 80}, 
  {id: 1, amount: 70}, 
  {id: 1, amount: 20}, 
  {id: 3, amount: 60}, 

  ]
let result = [];
array.reduce(function(total ,
currentValue) {
 if (!total[currentValue.id]) {
     console.log('currentValue:',currentValue);
     let key=currentValue.id
    total[key] = { id:key, amount: 0 };
  
    result.push(total[currentValue.id])
  }
  total[currentValue.id].amount += currentValue.amount;
  return total;
}, {});

console.log('result',result)
```

La solución mas optima que veo es mediante Reduce
así usamos Functional Programming With Javascript
reduce toma sus datos solo de sus parametros,y retorna un valor siempre retornara el mismo valor para el mismo argumento
fácil de depurar porque las funciones puras no tienen efectos secundarios ni están ocultas
puede esperar para evaluar los resultados cuando los necesite y memorizar los resultados ya que los resultados nunca cambian mientras la entrada no cambie
el código funcional es más fácil de probar y depurar.

```
arr.reduce(callback(acumulador, valorActual[, índice[, array]])[, valorInicial])
```

El acumulador (total) contendra a un unico valor final

> El reducer es la acción que realizaremos para llegar a un valor final
>
> Nuestro acumulador (total)comienza con {}, que es nuestro objeto
> inicial que pasamos al reducer lo modificamos inicialmente para que
> sus claves tengan como valor a un solo item del array sin repetir nos
> quedara inicialmente:

```
total: {
 '1': { id: 1, amount: 20 },
 '2': { id: 2, amount: 80 },
 '3': { id: 3, amount: 50 } 
 }
```

asi al hacer

```
  result.push(total[currentValue.id])
```

nos quedara inicialmente

```
result: [
 { id: 1, amount: 20 },
 { id: 3, amount: 50 },
 { id: 2, amount: 0 } 
 ]
```

**Luego al tener la misma referencia total[currentValue.id]  en relacion a los items de result
estos mostraran los valores acumulados**
Es interesante ver como se complica intentar resolver algo tan aparentemente simple

Comment: ¿Podrías fundamentar por qué la solución más óptima _parece ser_ con `arr.reduce(callback, initialValue);`? ¿Has hecho pruebas de ejecución?

Comment: otras soluciones son menos legibles y requieren mayor cantidad de codigo y son menos eficientes me parece!No se trata de nano optimización o micro optimización  o  instrucciones que se ejecutan decenas de miles de veces por segundo o menos que las denpminamos simplemente optimizaciónes

Comment: Lo preguntaba porque el OP no mencionó qué criterios considera para considerar que una solución es óptima o no, y en este caso, la métrica tampoco es mencionada en la respuesta. De mi parte, no hacía referencia a una cuestión de pareceres.

Comment: el código funcional es más fácil de probar y depurar